# How to return an int from CoroutineScope Kotlin?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am new in android development and I can't figure out, how to return an int in Coroutine from firestore...

Here is my function code:

```
    fun getSharesNumber(context: Context, name:String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            var trade1:Trade
            var sharesNumber:Int
            tradesCollectionRef.document(name)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                        trade1 = it.toObject(Trade::class.java)!!
                            sharesNumber = trade1.shares
                    }.await()
        }catch (e:Exception){
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                Toast.makeText(context,"$e",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to return shareNumber when calling this function.

Comment: You cant return a value from a coroutine to a non-suspending function unless you use `runBlocking`, which can trigger an ANR error and should never be used in UI code. Make the function `suspend` if you need a return value, and use `withContext` insted of `CoroutineScope`/`launch` to return a value.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please add this information as an answer, as it describes and provides a really good feed-back.

Comment: @Tenfour04 could you please edit my code to correct one in an answer?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return a value from a coroutine to a non-suspending function unless you use `runBlocking`, which can trigger an ANR error and should never be used in UI code. Make the function suspend if you need a return value, and use `withContext` instead of `CoroutineScope`/`launch` to return a value that has to be computed on a background thread.

You don't need to use `suspendCoroutine` when the library you're using already provides an `await()` suspend function. Since `await` is a suspend function, you don't have to call it with a specific dispatcher either and you don't need to deal with callbacks, so your code can become:

```
suspend fun getSharesNumber(context: Context, name:String): Int {
    return try {
        tradesCollectionRef.document(name).get().await()
            .toObject(Trade::class.java)?.shares
            ?: error("Document $name doesn't exist.")
    } catch (e:Exception){
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            Toast.makeText(context, "$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        -1
    }
}
```

where it's returning -1 in case of failure. Alternatively, you could just let it throw the exception and catch it higher up. It would more Kotlin-idiomatic to return null for failure rather than throwing, though. I didn't test this since I don't use Firestore, so the syntax might be off slightly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I searched for this on stackoverflow a lot, but didn't get a good example. Now I can understand how to return a value from a coroutine even if I did it a little bit differently. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the suspendCoroutine function to see if it can match your needs

```
    suspend fun getSharesNumber(context: Context, name:String): Int {
        return suspendCoroutine {
            try {
                var trade1:Trade
                var sharesNumber:Int
                tradesCollectionRef.document(name)
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            trade1 = it.toObject(Trade::class.java)!!
                            sharesNumber = trade1.shares

                            // return int
                            it.resume(sharesNumber)

                        }.await()
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
                it.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use `suspendCoroutine` when `await()` is already available? The existence of the `await()` function makes the Task class coroutine-compatible, so there's no need to enter callback hell.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, you make a lot of sense, thank you for your answer, I have read your answer, your way is excellent